# How to resolve pycosat dependency of conda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, conda-build

I am trying to install conda. But it is showing me missing dependency of `pycosat`. I am trying to build and install python-pycosat 0.6.3. I have downloaded the zip file from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pycosat/#files). I have extracted it and from inside ran `sudo python setup.py install`.

It gave me the result:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running install_lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/pycosat.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -> /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/test_pycosat.py -> /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/test_pycosat.py to test_pycosat.cpython-39.pyc
running install_egg_info
Writing /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pycosat-0.6.3-py3.9.egg-info
```

But after that when I still try to install conda, it is still saying that pycosat is missing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Conda with an installer, not through Python. The PyPI package is extremely outdated and was last tested on Python 3.6.

Consider trying [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#readme) or one of its variants.